# Book on UNIX Internals for practical aspects of architecture design

Tags: unix

Recently I've started Operating Systems course...now going through its contents I'm thinking about learning UNIX from its internals.Also I have completed a Computer Architecture course and really loved it.Can you suggest a good book on UNIX Internals from which I can learn the practical aspects of how the architecture designs work in a real life OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanenbaum's books are quite good: the one with lot of details about the MINIX source code is 
described here http://www.minix3.org/documentation/index.html. However, this is not the best of the serie: the source code description is rather messy.

A great classic on a historical version of Unix is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%27_Commentary_on_UNIX_6th_Edition,_with_Source_Code

Comment: Thanks...I have also started reading "The Design of the UNIX Operating System" by M.J.Bach...feeling it's useful also...

Comment: Yes, much more high level but very nice book. On that line I would also suggest Vahalia UNIX Internals: The New Frontiers: unfortunately is an old book (1995) but it surveys several design choices in different flavours of Unix.